# Why would you use output buffering around jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, output-buffering

I'm working on a file that already has some code, and it uses php's ob_start() and ob_get_clean() functions around the jQuery being used. Is there a clear reason for why someone would do this?

```php
  ob_start();
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.scripture').on('click', function() {
      $('div#schedule div.text').slideUp();
      text = $(this).next('div.text');
      
      if (text.is(":visible") == true) {
        text.slideUp();
      } else {
        text.slideDown();
      }
    });
    });
</script>

<?php
  $additionalJS = (!empty($additionalJS)) ? $additionalJS : NULL;
  $additionalJS .= ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with jQuery. It's just a way to concatenate `$additionalJS` with the HTML code.

Comment: You might do something like this if you're using PHP to dynamically generate some part of the JS, but that's not happening here, so ... not sure? It's a rather roundabout way to do `$additionalJS = 'a really long string';` -- maybe the author wanted to maintain indentation and didn't want to use a heredoc.